# Prove the following: Let V be a finitely generated vector space then V has a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof

If V is a finetely generated vector space then there exists a finite set of vectors $S=(v_1,.....,v_n)$ such that S spans V. We don't know if the set of vectors is a basis but we do know that the basis has at most n vectors.

My professor crossed out the claim "We don't know if the set of vectors is a basis but we do know that the basis has at most n vectors." and replaced it with "assume S is minimal, then S is a basis"

I don't know if replacing the crossed out statement with my professor's claim suffices the validity of the proof.

Comment: What proof? You've only showed claims, no proof at all of anything.

Comment: does putting the word proof fix the problem?

Comment: A proof is not determined by putting the word "proof" in front of a bunch of words.

Comment: Then how can I prove it. Actually that's not true, after the word proof, there is always a bunch of words. If there is no words, that would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think a proof could go more or less as follows: if $\;V=\{0\}\;$ there's nothing to prove, as by definition $\;\emptyset\;$ is a basis. Otherwise, take $\;0\neq v_1\in V\;$ . If Span$\{ v_1\}=V\;$ we've finished as clearly $\;\{v_1\}\;$ is a *minimal* generating set and thus a basis, otherwise there's $\;v_2\notin\text{Span}\,\{v_1\}\;$ , so $\;B_2:=\{v_1,v_2\}\;$ is linearly independent. If $\;\text{Span}\,B=V\;$ we've finished as we then have a generating linearly independent set and thus a basis, otherwise...etc.

The above process must end after a finite number of steps as we're assuming $\;V\;$ is finitely generated.

Comment: The empty set is a basis?. I didn't know that. Can you further elaborate on that?. It's good to know.

Comment: @TheMathNoob Is more of a definition though it is firmly based on the foundations. We had a rather exhaustive discussion on this back in undergraduate times, and it was based, if I remember correctly, on the fact that there's one unique function from the empty set to *any* set, meaning that the only subset of a cartesian product $\;\emptyset\times A\;,\;\;A\;$ any set,  is always the empty set itself...

Comment: your proof looks more like a program. You are basically starting with the base case which is the empty set and then you start saying for all v in V, if(v is independent with the other vectors in B) then append v in B.

Comment: Yes. Some proofs are just like this. I supose that one could even change things a little and try an induction proof...